# Find first word duplicate (match similar last names)

Tags: regex

I have a list of authors. They may be listed as

- `LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME` or
- `LASTNAME, F.` or
- `LASTNAME, F`

What would be a regex to find all the records that have the same `LASTNAME`? That way I could decide whether to merge the records or to keep them separate if they are authors with different first names.

Comment: What programming language are you using? In what format is that list? Is the list sorted?

Comment: @Shachi: Your edit had completely destroyed the question. Please be more careful. And whoever approved his edit, please watch what you're doing.

Comment: oh,I am really very sorry.  @TimPietzcker  Thanks for giving light to this. I will take utmost care that this doesnt happen agn. (I must say the wrong edit should not have been approved.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will always match the first word at the beginning of the line, which should be the last name:

```
/^\w+/
```

Use this to find the last names.  Then do something like this:

- Store the last names and full names in an associative array or an equivalent structure available in your programming language.
- Whenever you come to a new line, check if the last name already exists in your list.

  - If it exists, compare the full names and decide which one you want to keep.
  - If it does not exist, add it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try that out. I am using Gephi to visualize GraphML data, and I need to clean up some bibliometric entries in there. Gephi allows to create new columns based on Regex searches.